# Trying to access array offset on value of type null in Laravel 8

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, database, laravel-8

I'm making a Laravel website, and I wanted to show the names of the fields based on their ID.

```
@foreach($allData as $key => $amount)
<tr>
<td>{{$key+1}}</td>
<td>{{$amount['fee_category']['name']}}</td> <!-- ERROR LINE -->
<td>
     <a href="" class="btn btn-info"> Editar </a>
     <a href="" class="btn btn-danger" id="delete"> Eliminar </a>
</td>
</tr>
@endforeach
```

However, I am getting an error in the title. I am using the model to create a function that joins the two tables to relate the ID to the name.

```php
public function fee_category()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(FeeCategory::class,'fee_category_id'.'id');
}
```

I use this function in the controller to return the view with the data extracted from the table.

```php
public function ViewFeeAmount()
{
    $data['allData'] = FeeCategoryAmount::select('fee_category_id')
      ->groupBy('fee_category_id')
      ->get();

    return view('backend.setup.fee_amount.view_fee_amount',$data);
}
```

I already tried using composer update to update the project's composer, but I still have the same results.

Comment: Not sure if this is the issue, but `belongsTo(FeeCategory::class,'fee_category_id'.'id')` should be `belongsTo(FeeCategory::class,'fee_category_id', 'id')` (you had a period instead of a comma)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It might be that you're trying to access an array element that doesn't exist or is null. In your Blade/view try the following.

```
@foreach($allData as $key => $amount)
<tr>
    <td>{{$key+1}}</td>
    <td>{{ optional($amount['fee_category'])->name }}</td>
    <td>
         <a href="" class="btn btn-info"> Editar </a>
         <a href="" class="btn btn-danger" id="delete"> Eliminar </a>
    </td>
</tr>
@endforeach
```